# Error: Unsupported operation: Platform._localeName

Tags: flutter, flutter-web

I am using dart.io package and trying to detect the current locate of the system using Platform.localeName like this

```
WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
String defaultSystemLocale = Platform.localeName;
print('$defaultSystemLocale');
```

But when I run the app in Chrome (Web), I am getting this error

```
Error: Unsupported operation: Platform._localeName
    at Object.throw_ [as throw] (http://localhost:62284/dart_sdk.js:5061:11)
    at Function._localeName (http://localhost:62284/dart_sdk.js:54692:17)
    at Function.localeName (http://localhost:62284/dart_sdk.js:54698:71)
    at Function.get localeName [as localeName] (http://localhost:62284/dart_sdk.js:54574:27)
    at main (http://localhost:62284/packages/testapp/main4.dart.lib.js:97:45)
```

Any idea why?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

If you are getting `Platform` from `dart:io`, it is not supported on web ([see this website](https://dart.dev/guides/libraries)). You can import it from [universal_io](https://pub.dev/packages/universal_io) instead.

Comment: Got you. Thanks! Although it is returning en-US. I was expecting en_US. Not a big deal.